# Lag in output of AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I am currently trying to implement a very simple UIView to replace the UIImagePickerController and am running into lag with the image being captured.

Here is the class I am currently using:
https://gist.github.com/963319

When I call snapPicture the delegate gets back the image with correct dimensions instantaneously from captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer but does not display the image for at least 3 seconds and sometimes takes up to 5 or 10 seconds.  I have tried adding in the delegate setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout.  Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here or what might be causing this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs of AVCaptureAudioDataOutput say "All delegate methods are called on the specified dispatch queue", so the answer below from Alex could well indicate the problem.

If you do something like this instead of the current delegate callback:

[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(usePicture:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];

The -usePicture: method then invokes the delegate with the new picture.

Works for me. Though only tested on iPhone 4 for now.

Regards,
Edwin

Comment: As it turns out it did have to do with trying to update the image on the wrong thread.  Thank you.

Comment: One addition: I changed the waitUntilDone: parameter to YES, since the image is released when the autorelease pool is drained later on in the capture callback, so you could have a race condition with delegate call on the main thread, if that has not yet retained the image before it is released from the capture method, you have a problem...

Comment: I believe performSelector retains its object, so you should be fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you switch to main thread/queue when updating the UI in camView:didCaptureImage:? Updating UI from threads other than main causes issues.